# Camera Android App Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-camera, android-sharedpreferences

I'm creating an android app which will take photo graph and you can add description to it like Place Taken,Who is in the Pic etc.But I don't know how I can save it together and list in in another Intent.

I have Created the Capture Event

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_obstera);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

And the code below will Display it

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to add description to it and save it together and to list all of the saved images in an another Intent.

Do any one have a sample code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inserting large amount of data(like images) into database SQLite can be used,converting our image to byte array and store into SQLite.

**Here we See One Example which is Store Employee Details Like**

*Employee Name*

*Employee Photo*

*Employee Age*

For Employee Name we use text datatype and for Employee Age integer datatype.But to Store Employee Photo which datatype ? at that time we use BLOB datatype.

`insertEmpDetails()` method which is taken Employee Class as parameter and it store all Employee information into Employees Table.
here we can see before inserting image into database,we should  be convert your Bitmap image to byte array for that we are using Utility class getBytes()method.

`retriveEmpDetails()` method which is retrieve Employee Details from Database and return Employee Object.
To get all Name,Photo,Age we use Corresponding getXXX() methods.
At the time of retriving photo we will get blob[] array of image.at that time we need to convert byte array to image.for that purpose we use getPhoto() method in Utility class which will convert our blob array into Bitmap image and retrun Bitmap image.

**UI Layout(activity_main.xml)**

This layout used to view

*Employee Name*

*Employee Photo*

*Employee Age*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EMPLOYEE_NAME" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="NAME" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EMPLOYEE_PHOTO" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EMPLOYEE_AGE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="AGE" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Android Activity(InsertandRetriveBlobData.java)**

```
package com.androidsurya.sqliteexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InsertandRetriveBlobData extends Activity {
 private DBhelper DbHelper;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  DbHelper = new DBhelper(this);
  Employee employee_One = new Employee(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    getResources(), R.drawable.photo), "Surya", 25);
  DbHelper.open();
  DbHelper.insertEmpDetails(employee_One);
  DbHelper.close();
  employee_One = null;
  DbHelper.open();
  employee_One = DbHelper.retriveEmpDetails();
  DbHelper.close();

  TextView empname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
  empname.setText(employee_One.getName());
  ImageView empphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
  empphoto.setImageBitmap(employee_One.getBitmap());
  TextView empage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);
  empage.setText("" + employee_One.getAge());

  }
}
```

**DBhelper.java**

This is database class here we declare

`insertEmpDetails()` method to insert employee details and
`retriveEmpDetails()` method to retrive employee details

```
package com.androidsurya.sqliteexample;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBhelper {
 public static final String EMP_ID = "id";
 public static final String EMP_NAME = "name";
 public static final String EMP_AGE = "age";
 public static final String EMP_PHOTO = "photo";

  private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EmployessDB.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static final String EMPLOYEES_TABLE = "Employees";

  private static final String CREATE_EMPLOYEES_TABLE = "create table "
   + EMPLOYEES_TABLE + " (" + EMP_ID
   + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + EMP_PHOTO
   + " blob not null, " + EMP_NAME + " text not null unique, "
   + EMP_AGE + " integer );";

  private final Context mCtx;

  private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEES_TABLE);
  }

   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EMPLOYEES_TABLE);
   onCreate(db);
  }
 }

  public void Reset() {
  mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
 }

  public DBhelper(Context ctx) {
  mCtx = ctx;
  mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
 }

  public DBhelper open() throws SQLException {
  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }

  public void close() {
  mDbHelper.close();
 }

  public void insertEmpDetails(Employee employee) {
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(EMP_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(employee.getBitmap()));
  cv.put(EMP_NAME, employee.getName());
  cv.put(EMP_AGE, employee.getAge());
  mDb.insert(EMPLOYEES_TABLE, null, cv);
 }

  public Employee retriveEmpDetails() throws SQLException {
  Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, EMPLOYEES_TABLE, new String[] { EMP_PHOTO,
    EMP_NAME, EMP_AGE }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
   byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHOTO));
   String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME));
   int age = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_AGE));
   cur.close();
   return new Employee(Utility.getPhoto(blob), name, age);
  }
  cur.close();
  return null;
 }
}
```

**Utility.java**

Utility class is main role here
Before inserting image and retrive image from SQLite Database we use these below methods.
`getBytes()` Convert bitmap image to byte array and retrun byte[]
`getPhoto()` convert byte[] to bitmap and retrun bitmap image

```
package com.androidsurya.sqliteexample;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class Utility {
 // convert from bitmap to byte array
 public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
  return stream.toByteArray();
 }

  // convert from byte array to bitmap
 public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
  return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
 }
}
```

**Register Android Activity in AndroidManifest file**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.androidsurya.sqliteexample.InsertandRetriveBlobData"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use another way which I have used.When you call the  camera intent then it will create a file name under the folder.When you come back into `onActivityResult` you will get this file name.

```
        file_image = createImageFile();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(
                "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file_image));
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT_VIDEO);
```

For creating the `createImageFile` you can use this way

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    final String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    final File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    final File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,
            JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}

private File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
            .getExternalStorageState())) {
        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory
                .getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                    Log.e("directory", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name),
                "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }
    return storageDir;
}

private String getAlbumName() {
    return getString(R.string.app_name);
}
```

When you call `onActivityResult` u will get the content

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)   {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            final Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file_image);}
```

Also you will get the all image List into folder which you create from album name.